# Core Graphics memory leaks while displaying pdf images

Tags: ios, pdf, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I have a subclass of UIImageView view that loads pdf image data, so that I can have a resolution independent graphic in my view. Works well for the stated purpose, but I am getting memory leaks with this, according to an instruments leaks profile.

Here is the code below that I believe should be responsible for the leaks. I am trying to track down the problem, but I am a little foggy on how to pinpoint the issue.

```
- (id)initWithPDFResourceAtPath:(NSString *)path center:(CGPoint)center {
    if ((self = [super init])){
        CGPDFPageRelease(pageRef);
        CGPDFDocumentRef documentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]);
        pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);
        CGPDFPageRetain(pageRef);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(documentRef);
        [self setBounds];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setBounds {
    [self setBounds:CGRectApplyAffineTransform(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleH, scaleV))];
    size = self.bounds.size;
    [self getPDFimage];
}

-(void)getPDFimage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleH, scaleV);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);
    [self setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
}
```

Comment: Although it's not an answer, you could also just display the pdf using a UIWebView and have it handle all the leak prevention.

Comment: Did you try static analyzer? It can show you potential leak places in the code.

Comment: @MarkM very interesting. I will look into that. Do you have any specific material you can point me to?

Comment: @Jeepston, thanks, I did, nothing is picked up as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your `pageRef` variable leaks -- You retain it, but never release it, you should do that in `dealloc`. Releasing it before you retain it in your `init` method is pointless, you're just releasing a null pointer, which has no effect (if you were using `CFRelease` instead of `CGPDFPageRelease`, it would crash).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`. Change your code to:

```
UIImage *image = [self setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

EDIT1: your code has this pageRef variable - is it an ivar or a static? If an ivar you better release it with CGPDFPageRelease() in the dealloc method. [It really should be an ivar]

EDIT2: See attached screen shot on Object Alloc. You can see the type and current amount and its ordered from most to least.

[image]

EDIT3: all else fails create a demo project that has the same problem and post it on Dropbox.

EDIT4: Code was uploaded to: [here](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/StampsTest-transparency.zip) (I cannot look at it til May 28th)

EDIT5: The problem is that pageRef is not ever released. So:

1) remove this from your init method, as it does nothing:

```
CGPDFPageRelease(pageRef);
```

2 and move it to a new dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    CGPDFPageRelease(pageRef);
}
```

Comment: Did you use ObjectAlloc in Instruments, run your app enough to get lots of memory leaked, then see WHAT is getting leaked - why kind of object(s)?

Comment: Thanks. Is that the "Responsible Caller?"

Comment: I updated the answer. There are oodles of posts here on using Object Alloc and Leaks in Instruments. As you can see from what I uploaded, you may just see malloced objects, in which case your job is harder. Hopefully you will see some object that you recognize, like CGImageRef. You did see my first EDIT, right?

Comment: thanks! I added the dealloc as you described, but still have the same situation. I am seeing what you are showing in instruments, but I am new with it and not that clear on what to look for yet.

Comment: I have been looking into this some more. turns out that only pdf graphics that have transparency cause the leaks.

Comment: If you can get one image and create a demo project that shows the leak, I'd like to see it as well as report the bug to Apple (which you can do too - but you need a demo project that shows it). One image that gets loaded repeatedly then freed, that leaks, is perfect for the demo app to give Apple.

Comment: Well I can do it (but I'll have to look into how), but I'll post the project shortly and notify here. And feel free to post the bug report!

Comment: Here is a sample: owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/StampsTest-transparency.zip